# JOIN on where data, or put it in the where clause?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join a subset of data from one table with data in another table (example below), and from a performance standpoint, i'm wondering what the best way to do this is, and what is most scalable.

The table I am trying to join looks like this (the other tables are already in the query).

```
vid             kid         uid
1                34          12
1                34          15
2                22          18
2                34          18
2                22          15
```

My query is like this

```
SELECT * FROM similar 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN(SELECT event.stuff,  eventdate.stuffshows
FROM events
JOIN evendate ON events.eid=eventdate.eid
WHERE location= 'Paris'
AND event.date
BETWEEN '2009-08-14'
AND '2009-08-17'
GROUP BY event.date
ORDER BY event.date
LIMIT 0 , 5
) mystuff ON event.bid = similar.id
AND event.date=similar.date
```

I think I can make it into

```
SELECT * FROM similar 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN(SELECT event.stuff,  eventdate.stuffshows
FROM events
JOIN evendate ON events.eid=eventdate.eid
WHERE 
user.vid=events.vid AND user.uid=15 AND user.kid=22
location= 'Paris'
AND event.date
BETWEEN '2009-08-14'
AND '2009-08-17'
GROUP BY event.date
ORDER BY event.date
LIMIT 0 , 5
) mystuff ON event.bid = similar.id
AND event.date=similar.date
```

My concern is that I'm kinda mixing a join with a where. Is it worth it for performance to set a second JOIN for user.vid=events.vid? Or is it better to do a WHERE rather than a join?

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: pedalpete: I'm a little thrown off by your last WHERE clause (event.date = similar.date).  I recommend you move that statement either to the OUTER JOIN condition or to the subquery itself.  As it stands, event.date shouldn't be visible to the outside query.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in the differences in performance, the easiest way to find out is to preface your SELECT statements with EXPLAIN.  You'll see which indices are used and how many rows need to be touched, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a rule of thumb and the performance is equivalent I use what makes it the most logical for my understanding. I put the fields that define the join between the two tables on the join clause, and the filtering conditions in the where clause. Generally you know you have it right if you write a similar query and the join conditions stay the same and only the where clause changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to directly answer this question.  Placing a restriction within the "where" or "on" clauses doesn't matter in the long run.  mySQL will optimize them both to effectively run the same query (which, as dnagirl explains, you can see by using EXPLAIN). A tool like mysql workbench can show you the relative times it takes to run a query so that will also help answer questions like these.  For this particular one, because the queries are basically equivalent, you can use Jay's suggestion, and just go with the one you feel makes things more readable.